# Can the .git folder be copied or moved

Tags: git

I have a folder called `application` which I intend to run GIT from. I will add all files, commit and upload as the master branch.

I also have a folder called `application_new` which is a later version of `application` and I would like to upload the differences as a later commit/push.

I started this project pre-git or thinking about it so my question is: If I copy the hidden `.git` folder from application to application_new will GIT automatically detect all the changes between my two versions? Or do I need to runs like a "refresh" for GIT to detect the differences?

Comment: Please be careful, after it's done! You should delete `application` and keep only `application_new` or you'll be tempted to use both and create useless conflicts with yourself. My recommandation: copy the content of `application_new` to `application`, commit, and only keep one repository.

Comment: That thought crossed my mind about copying the contents. My folders are actually labeled application_1.5 or application_1.6 etc so shouldn't be a problem but thank you for the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy git folder to whatever project you want and it will detect all changes. If that is later version of project I think it will go smooth as one commit.

Maybe only thing that you might want to pay attention is .gitignore file because if you changed it in meantime you can expect some unexpected behavior, but that should not be problem at all.

Comment: Thanks - so literally copy .git and then commit - no refresh etc?

Comment: Nope, because in .git you have snapshot of last commit state, so weather you change folders and files in folder with .git or you move .git folder when you do `git status` or `git diff` you will see changes relative to last snapshot.